# Organize data properly in mysql

Tags: mysql

So to my knowledge there is no sets, lists, dicts, or arrays in mysql.  I want to build a system that has two core components, information about a game match, and then a list of the characters played in the match.  If there were lists in mysql then I would do something like this:

```
game_id INT,
characters list<varchar>,
....more data
```

The basic query that I want to be able to do is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM games WHERE characters IN LIST(list);
```

Its possible I may select with only one character, or i may specify 10 characters.  The question is how to do this efficiently in mysql versus using 10 `WHERE` clauses with `OR`.  There is also no specific ordering to the characters...but I suppose I could order them based on their IDs.

The only way I have thought of doing this nicely is creating the first table with the basic information and a second table with just character ids and the game_id.

Anyone have a suggestion on how to organize this data nicely with some fancy mysql tricks that I may not know about?  The queries need to be fast too, as there will probably be a lot of them eventually.  It will be way more reads than writes unless I add a view/download counter....than i guess it will be more writes/updates than reads.

Thanks and I am happy to give anymore information.

Comment: You've come close to answering your own question: "The only way I have thought of doing this nicely is creating the first table with the basic information and a second table with just character ids and the game_id."  That sounds like a SQLish way of doing things.  Since you want to use MySQL, your solution is going to have to be something like this.  The List idea won't work per se, because, as you say intimate, that's just not how SQL does things.  @neokio has given some specific ideas that may help, too.

Comment: @DWright What other systems would you suggest?  You make it sound like there are better systems that this query could be created in.  I know some of NoSQL, but to my knowledge it would not be of much use to me since the `WHERE` conditions may not be constant and could be a bunch of filters...

Comment: Don't really know NOSQL--my point was that to do this in SQL, you'll want to do it in a way that fits SQL--modeled reasonably well via multiple tables that join together in a useful way, (beyond the use of IN()). What you mentioned, two tables that store and relate game ids and character ids is more promising than the concept of a list per se, because it sounds more like SQL. I haven't done well articulating my intuition . . . But it seems like you're already having the right kinds of SQL intutions when you talk about multiple tables--these can be joined and it's all about the joins in SQL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two ways I can think of, if I understand your question correctly....

**METHOD 1** ... adding a `game_characters` table that looks like ...

```
CREATE TABLE `games_characters` (
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `games` (`game_id`),
  KEY `characters` (`character_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

... then the query would be something like ...

```
SELECT *
FROM `games` as g
LEFT JOIN `games_characters` as gc
  ON (g.`id` = gc.`game_id`)
WHERE gc.`character_id` IN (12,52,86,23)
```

**METHOD 2** ... using LIKE, less ideal for large databases, but avoids an extra table ... the `characters` record would contain a bunch of ids from another table, `characters`, delimited by a period like so ".23.51.252.75.93.". The query would look like

```
SELECT *
FROM `games`
WHERE `characters` LIKE '%.23.%'
   OR `characters` LIKE '%.58.%'
```

Your CMS would have to parse and rebuild the string.

Comment: What's the performance of the first query?  By that will it be say 20-30ms or something low at least?  Also how well will MYSQL scale when there are 10 million rows in games_characters ( 1 million games per say )?

Comment: Are there any good `KEY` systems to match `game_id` and `chracter_id` in your example?

Comment: for 10 million rows, method 1 will have superior performance, and yes i'd guess 15-30ms for that simple query. you'll definitely want to include an index ... i'll update the create table above now

Comment: So i'm just curious, are there any fancy dual primary keys in MYSQL? Something like `PRIMARY KEY(`game_id`, `character_Id`) and if so wouldn't this be more efficient than just using a standard index?

Comment: Great question for someone who knows more than I ... but if you wanted to try it, I'd love to know the result! ... CREATE TABLE `games_characters` (
  `game_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `character_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `games_to_characters` (`game_id`,`character_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;